# how to remove default commands from key preferences page in eclipse Rcp?

Tags: eclipse-rcp

In my General -->key preferences pages default command exist for example Activate Editor =F12, 
New =ctrl+N and so on. I just want to remove these default commands and wants to add my own custom commands.

Comment: You should really define your own scheme and set that as the default (in the plugin_customization.ini)

Comment: Could you Plz tell me, How to define own scheme as default? how to remove unwanted default commands? i really don't have any idea...

Comment: See [this](http://www.vogella.com/tutorials/EclipseCommandsKeybindings/article.html) tutorial

Comment: Actually I have defined my own scheme using these tutorial but i have to remove existing default emacs command for key preferences